# What is the shortest way to instantiate a list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Say I have a data type `Person` defined as follows, using record syntax:

```
data Person = Person { name :: String
                     , age  :: Int
                     } deriving (Show)
```

And I instantiate a list of `Person`s using:

```
people = [Person {name="Alice",   age=27},
          Person {name="Bob",     age=23},
          Person {name="Mallory", age=26}]
```

I then realize that defining many elements of the list at a time would be bulky, since the words `name` and `age` are repeated. I thus reduce the code to:

```
people = [(Person "Alice"   27),
          (Person "Bob"     23),
          (Person "Mallory" 26)]
```

Since lists in Haskell are homogenous anyway, how can I avoid specifying the type `Person` in every element of the list? For example, doing something along the lines of the following code (which doesn't compile):

```
Person people = [("Alice"   27),
                 ("Bob"     23),
                 ("Mallory" 26)]
```

[Link to runnable example](http://rextester.com/WSJVS90299)

Comment: The last example is just a list of tuples. Couldn't you just create a function that takes a list of tuples and `map`s `Person` over the list?

Comment: @Carcigenicate: no, it is not, here you apply `27` to `"Alice"`, and this will fail.

Comment: You can use `map (uncurry Person) [("Alice", 27), ("Bob", 23), ...]`.

Comment: You are not specifying the type `Person`; you are specifying the value constructor `Person`, and it can't be eliminated because there is no a priori reason to believe that is the only way to make a `Person`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Person`, as a constructor for data value, is itself a (binary) function. You may build this list from a list of tuples:

```
people = map (uncurry Person) [("Alice", 27), ("Bob", 42)]
```

or you can build it from a list of names and list of ages:

```
people = zipWith Person ["Alice", "Bob"] [27, 42]
```

... or from plenty of other options.

Answer (score 3):

Joke answer:

```
instance Enum Person where
    toEnum i = Person (show i) i
    fromEnum (Person _ i) = i

personList :: [Person]
personList = [toEnum 0..]
```

Still a joke answer:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.String

instance IsString Person where
        fromString ps =
           let (name,read . drop 1 -> age) = break (==':') ps
           in Person name age

personList :: [Person]
personList = ["Me:30"
             ,"Them:55"
             ]
```

Twisted joke answer:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances#-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.String

instance IsString (Int -> Person) where
        fromString = Person

data Person = Person { name :: String
                     , age  :: Int
                     } deriving (Show)

($$) :: (Int -> Person) -> Int -> Person
($$) = ($)

persons :: [Person]
persons = ["Me" $$ 30, "Them" $$ 55]
```

The commented answer:

```
personList = map (uncurry Person) [("Me",30), ("Them", 55)]
```

The bad answer:

```
personList = zipWith Person ["Me", "Them"] [30,55]
```

Answer (score 1):

One doesn’t tend to need to represent large amounts of literal data much in Haskell so we may be glad that the language does not optimise for their representation. Here are some options:

```
people = (
  let p = Person in
  [p "Alice"   27,
   p "Bob"     23,
   p "Mallory" 26]
)
```

Or with some basic parsing

```
people = (
  let p x = p' (words x)
      p' [name, age] = person name (read age) in
  map p $ lines "Alice 27\nBob 23\n Mallory 26"
)
```

Or just do it however you like then do `show people` and by default that will be in Haskell syntax so just put it somewhere at the bottom of a source file and forget about it.